# component inside material table cell is not rendered correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here is the [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1kgyk) showing the problem.

I want to have a material progress bar inside my material table.

Version 1

- everything works as expected

Version 2

- Col: `Name` where I use the `mat-progress-bar` directly works
- Col: `Symbol` where I use a component with `mat-progress-bar` does not work.

### Questions:

- Why is Version 2 not working as expected?
- Is this a bug?

(I want to use Version2 because I have CSS-Styles that `CENTER` my columns so the table looks nice.)

Comment: Why you have  newComp in your version 2 instead of mat-progress-bar cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a css issue.

Adding `width: 100%` to your custom component tag should be enough here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'newComp',
  styles: [`
    :host {
      width: 100%;
    } 

  mat-progress-bar { height: 2em;}
  `],
  template: `...`,

})
export class newComp {
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1kgyk-ggxj5u?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)**

Comment: thank you sir! good spot. Would have taken me a long time to figure out myself.